# Tactics of implementing DC power supply to opamp in real layout

Tags: layout

I have built a circuit shown below. I need to build a layout for this circuit. Regarding the power supply, what is the best strategy for powering the DC voltage of the OPAMP?

I need some connector and I need routing from this connector to the OPAMP, what is the best way in general to implement it?

[image]

Comment: What will you be powering this from, the mains, battery, bench supply, ...? Is the primary power supply unipolar or bipolar? With that sort of gain, you may want to place a capacitor in series with R1 to lower the DC gain. Don't forget bypass capacitors in the final design. You may need to decouple the opamp power pins with a small resistance, perhaps 1 to 10 ohms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that the power supply of your opamps is max 5 V ...

> ... what is the best way in general to implement it? ...

The "faster" should be the "best" ... with the aid of decoupling capacitors (0.1uF) directly across the pins supply and ground ... and the help of some 10th of resistors values (not noted on my simulation).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> *Regarding the power supply, what is the best strategy for powering the
> DC voltage of the OPAMP?*

Based on the following: -

- The input range of the op-amp (from the [data sheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/62689f.pdf)) is from 0 to 4.5 volts
- i.e. from the most negative rail to 4.5 volts higher.
- Maximum voltage (negative rail to positive rail) is 5.5 volts
- You are using a mid-rail ground/0 volts connection

So, I would use a negative 2 volt rail and a positive 2.5 volt rail or, maybe +/- 2.5 volts. Each rail should be able to supply the output short circuit current of circa 60 mA plus the quiescent current of the device (15 mA).

But, the big **showstopper** is that you have simulated it assuming a +/- 12 volt rail and this will fry the device in an instant: -

[image]

Assuming that you need output voltage levels in excess of 2.5 volts positive or negative, I suggest you rethink which op-amp you should use: -

[image]

> *I need some connector and I need routing from this connector to the
> OPAMP, what is the best way in general to implement it?*

Once you have chosen a supply that meets your op-amp requirements use a 3 pin screw terminal connector on the circuit board is my advice. I'd also put reverse protection diodes from positive to 0 volts and from 0 volts to negative.

And, once you have chosen the supply be aware that the DC input offset voltage of each op-amp is up to +/- 0.7 mV. This means that there could be a DC offset from the first stage of a few tens of milli volt and, the 2nd stage might saturate on this offset. Yes you have overall negative feedback that limits the AC gain to 101 but, you still might suffer problems in this area.

Given that there is a glaring problem with the power supply expectancy, I'll leave any further recommendations until these are fixed. You should note that you can test the effects of input offsets within LTspice to find out what really happens.

Comment: Hello ,why do we need a 3 pin screw? we have plus and minus which is the gnd, where do i put the third gnd pin?i need to connect it to the minus?

Comment: @lub2354 you've accepted an answer and effectively closed down the session.